# What's the Microsoft Ajax equivalent to jquery.ajaxSetup() or .ajaxError()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that uses both Microsoft Ajax [`Ajax.BeginForm()`] and jQuery to make asynchronous requests. I want to configure both frameworks such that a generic error handler is automatically attached if the developer does not explicitly specify a failure callback.

In jQuery I can accomplish this with either [.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) or [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/). What is the equivalent in the Microsoft Ajax client library? I'm fairly sure it's something in the `Sys` object but I can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [client events of the PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384136%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) object. The equivalent of ajaxError seems to be [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) whereas the equivalent of ajaxSetup should be [initializeRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397460%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)